# Kendo Tooltip does not open after second touch on Safari Mobile

Tags: javascript, iphone, kendo-ui, safari, kendo-tooltip

Kendo tooltip works with hover on any desktop application and with touch with mobile devices, this works pretty cool in Android devices but with Safari in IOS the tooltip does not open after second touch,

hopefully somebody can help with this issue, the expected behavior is to open with first touch and close with the second,

Thanks in advance! I'm trying two options:

JS Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tooltip1").kendoTooltip();
});
```

Or:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tooltip1").kendoTooltip({
        showOn: "click",
        showOn: "mouseenter"
    });
});
```